# How to prevent the entry of a negative number or a number with more than 4 digits

Tags: java

I just want to find out if there is any way to block a user from entering either a negative number or a number with more than 4 digits. Also is there anyway to put this logic into a GUI? Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class EasterSunday
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int year; // declarations
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //start Scanner
        System.out.println("Enter in a year to find out the day and month of that Easter Sunday.");
        year = input.nextInt();
        int a = year%19;
        int b = year%4;
        int c = year%7;
        int d = (19 * a + 24) %30;
        int e = (2 * b + 4 * c + 6 * d + 5) %7;
        int eSunday = (22 + d + e);
        if ((year >= 1900) && (year <= 2099) && (year != 1954) && (year != 1981) && (year != 2049) && (year != 2076))
        {
            if (eSunday <= 30)
                System.out.println("Easter Sunday in " + year + " is March, " + eSunday);
            else
                System.out.println("Easter Sunday in " + year + " is April, " + (eSunday - 30));
        }
        else
        {
            if (eSunday <= 30)
                System.out.println("Easter Sunday in " + year + " is March, " + (eSunday - 7));
            else
                System.out.println("Easter Sunday in " + year + " is April, " + (eSunday - 37));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should ask one question and narrow down the code?

Comment: sorry new to this i know for next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) and restrict the characters to numbers with max length of 4. This covers negative numbers since the user can't enter the minus character.

Another solution is to use an [InputVerifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html) on a simple JTextField.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to use a while loop, and not to allow the user to exit until he's entered a number that meets your criteria.

```
number = -1;
// while either the non-negativity or four-digit condition is not met
while(number < 0 || number > 9999){
    number = requestInput(user);
}
```

with the function requestInput(user) which requests input from the user.  The initialization of number = -1 is necessary because if you simply declare it without initializing it (if memory serves), it will cause either your IDE to complain that it may not have been initialized, or the program will skip over the while loop altogether because 0 is in the range (0, 9999) inclusive.